# how to do a function to return row type from a table in pl/sql?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I made this function but it return an error when i execute it!

```
create or replace function get_accounts
(Acc_id in Account1.account_id%Type)
return account1%rowtype
as
l_cust_record account1%rowtype;
begin
select * into l_cust_record from account1
where account_id=Acc_id;
return(l_cust_record);
end;
/
```

Comment: How are you executing it?  What is the error?

Comment: execute Get_Accounts(account_id);
 and this is the error  PLS-00221: 'GET_ACCOUNTS' is not a procedure or is undefined

Comment: Are you using SQL Server or Oracle. Oracle is Pl\SQL and SQL Server is T-SQL

Comment: I removed the `sql-server` tag  because this is clearly PL/SQL

Comment: I use OracleSQL Developer ,,and i am just a beginner , i hope you can help me

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE account1 (
 account_id INT,
 name       VARCHAR2(20)
);

INSERT INTO account1 VALUES ( 1, 'Bob' );

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_accounts(
  Acc_id IN Account1.account_id%TYPE
) RETURN account1%ROWTYPE
AS
  l_cust_record account1%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
  SELECT *
  INTO   l_cust_record
  FROM   account1
  WHERE  account_id = Acc_id;

  RETURN l_cust_record;
END;
/
```

**PL/SQL Block**:

```
DECLARE
  r_acct ACCOUNT1%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
  r_acct := get_accounts( 1 );
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( r_acct.name );
END;
/
```

**Output**:

```
Bob
```

Answer (score 0):

To call a function in Oracle, you need to use its return value. That is, you can't call it as you would a procedure. Something like this would work:

```
declare
  myrow account1%rowtype;
  account_id Account1.account_id%Type := <VALID ACCOUNT ID VALUE>;
begin
  myrow := Get_Accounts(account_id); 
end;
/
```