# Turn SQL statement in a function

Tags: sql, oracle

How to replace a concrete value with a variable in Oracle SQL? I have

```
 select 5, min(id) from my_table where id > 5 --AND ..
 UNION ALL     
 select 6, min(id) from my_table where id > 6  --AND ..
 UNION ALL
 ....  

 | 5 | 6 |
 | 6 | 8 |
 ...
```

How to wrap it in a function executing pseudocode below?

```
for ( $i in ( select id from my_table)){
    UNION ALL
    select $i, min(id) from my_table where id > $i 
}
```

---

Edit: To make it clear, I am looking for a general method to turn a select with hard wired values into a function that accepts variables. Note the `--AND` part.

---

Edit2:
Let me translate it in Java.
Qu estion: I have code

```
  System.out.println(1+2+" = 1+2"+ " ");
```

that returns a sum of two numbers. How to replace concrete 1+2 with any `a` and `b`?
Answer:
You need to define

```
   int getSum(int a, int b){ return a+b;}
```

Now you can write

```
for(int a : setA){    
    for(int b : setB){    
        System.out.println(" " +a+"+"+b+" = "+ getSum(a,b)+" ");    
        }}
```

This way you can iterate over all elements of `setA` and all elements of `setB` instead of providing concrete values 1 and 2.

I have exactly the same question for SQL. If I have a query that returns a result for a concrete value (Java example: `1`,`2`; SQL example:  `where id > 6` ) - how to modify it so that SQL iterates over all possible values (obtained by select id from t group by id)?

Comment: I don't understand. What is your function supposed to return? The `select` statement returns a hard-coded number (5) and a `min(id)` from a table. But your pseudocode seems to return the result of a `UNION ALL`, meaning a set of rows. Do you need a function that returns an associative array, or a nested table, or some other kind of collection?

Comment: I looks like you want to have the next id for each id, is that right?

Comment: And why do you need a function for this? The analytic function `LEAD()`, available in standard SQL, already does that.

Comment: @GolezTrol @mathguy I want to turn a statement with `where something = 'concrete_value'` into my_function( $argument1) ->  `where something = $argument1`. I need this as a simple example of user defined function.

Comment: Functions in Oracle PLSQL are very powerful and can do all sorts of things. For queries with variables, you can typically use bind parameters and you don't need a function at all. Have you tried creating a simple function that returns your input, or returns your input * 2? If you have some of the basics, it's easier to step up from there and create functions that return a cursor or a table of data.

Comment: @GolezTrol yes, I've tried creating a simple function. I can't find a single working example of `select id, function(id).* from t` that would take get a set of `id` from table `t`, then feed each `id` in a function and return a tuple. As a result a table `id1 tuple_1(id1), tuple_2(id1) \n   id2 tuple_1(id2), tuple_2(id2) ..` is returned.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to get the next ID for each id. That can be done simply by using the [`lead`](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/lead.php) function:

```sql
select
  t.id,
  lead(t.id) over (order by t.id) as next_id
from
  my_table t
```

If you do want to return it from a function, you would probably need a table function returning a custom table type, because the rowtype to return doesn't match your table structure, so you can't use `my_table%rowtype`.

The snippet below would create such a row type and matching table type, and a function that would return the same as above query. The last lines contain the same query, now using the function instead of the table:

```
-- Define a row type (an object). 
create or replace type my_row_type as object (
  id int,
  next_id int
);

-- Define a table type of that row type
create type my_table_type as table of my_row_type;

-- Create a function that returns a table. 
create or replace function my_function
return my_table_type
is
  result my_table_type;
begin
  select
    -- Use the rowtype constructor to put the id and next_id into a row object
    my_row_type(
      t.id,
      lead(t.id) over (order by t.id))
  -- use bulk collect into to query all rows into the table variable 'result'
  bulk collect into
    result
  from
    my_table t;

  -- Don't forget to actually return it.
  return result;
end;
/

-- Query it by 'casting' the function result to a table.
select
  id,
  next_id
from
  table(my_function);
```

For more info on table functions, I think this tutorial/article is a good start:

http://stevenfeuersteinonplsql.blogspot.com/2015/04/table-functions-introduction-and.html

Comment: This is a query for a specific case only. Is there a general rule how to turn any statement with concrete `where value=5` into `where value = $arg_value`?

Comment: Yes, I think the term you're looking for is `binding` or `parameter`. You would write something like `where value = :value`, or `value = &value`, and depending on the application or context from which you are executing the query, you can fill in these values one way or another. That's the generic answer, but using searches like "How can I execute a query with parameters [in SQL developer/from PHP/in the CLI/whatever], you can probably find details for your situation.

Comment: See the Oracle  doc "[Binding and Defining](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/appdev.920/a96584/oci05bnd.htm)" for all the basic information about this topic.

Comment: And there are bunches of other examples and tutorials on how to create functions, which can be simple procedures, functions that return a single value, functions that return object, or tables of object, or which pipe their results... The sky is the limit, but I'm afraid your question is a bit too broad in that regard. Here is [The syntax for `Create Function`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_5009.htm), which has also links to various examples. Maybe that gets you started?

Comment: As that doc says (and I did to), a function can return almost anything. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36484546/how-to-do-a-function-to-return-row-type-from-a-table-in-pl-sql) shows how to return a row of a specific table type, but that doesn't apply here, because a) you want multiple rows (according to your question), and b) you have this `min(id)` which doesn't exist in the table, so the type you want to return doesn't match your table rowtype. So then you get into [collections and records](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/overview.htm#sthref229).

Comment: Anyway, added a function that returns the same thing as the query to the answer.

Comment: `my_function is not in a valid state` . Also, I want to use chained functions like in Python or Java. something like `select id, function_1(function_2(id), function_3(id)) from my_table`. Your example doesn't have a place to insert arguments to a function.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. I am looking for an algorithm to take a `select /*complicated stuff*/ where something = hardcoded_value1 /*more stuff*/` (say it returns (hardcoded_value1) -> (42 43), (hardcoded_value2) -> (34 35)  and turn it into a function that can return 'hardcoded_value1  42 43 \n hardcoded_value2 34 35 \n ...`  for each hardcoded_valueN in the table.

Comment: I've tried the second set of statements. It returns `MY_FUNCTION is in invalid state`

Comment: I'm sorry. I can't comprehend what you're asking. Hopefully somebody else can provide you with an answer.

Comment: "This question shows how to return a row of a specific table type" - doesn't work on my Oracle SQL workspace.

Comment: What Oracle SQL workspace is that then? Not MySQL I hope?

Comment: Oracle PL/SQL 12

Comment: Alright, then the code sample should work, provided you actually have a table called `my_table`. When you get or find samples, it could always be that they don't work _exactly_ as-is on your database, because the names might be faked. It helps if you know how to actually check for those kinds of things, and are able to modify the function a bit. If you have a tool like SQL Developer, you could try [this tutorial on debugging PLSQL](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/11g/r2/prod/appdev/sqldev/plsql_debug/plsql_debug_otn.htm).