# Invalid Identifier and return statement cannot contain expression in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, rowtype

I am trying to create function in PL/SQL but I am getting invalid identifier error

( for username VARCHAR2)  and

"In a procedure, RETURN statement cannot contain an expression" error.

I tried similar questions solutions about invalid identifer and return statemnt error but noone of them worked for me.

I couldn't fix the issue . Idk what's the reason for throwing error.

I am using oracle 19c with oracle sql developer

Can you help me ? Thanks in advance

My create function code :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION bring_product
(
username VARCHAR2
)
RETURN pr%ROWTYPE
AS
product_tbl pr%rowtype;
BEGIN

 SELECT *  INTO product_table FROM PRODUCT pr WHERE pr.kulusername = username ;

 RETURN product_tbl ;

END;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to do a function to return row type from a table in pl/sql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36484546/how-to-do-a-function-to-return-row-type-from-a-table-in-pl-sql)

Comment: No if you look my code same like that but code not working

Comment: Looks like the table is named `product_tbl`, not `pr`, so you probably wanted `product_tbl%rowtype`.

Comment: *"In a procedure, RETURN statement cannot contain an expression"* - this is true. Luckily, you are creating a function, not a procedure.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use a `table alias` for variable declaration of `%rowtype` attribute-style

**but** the `table name`. So, convert to the following one :

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION bring_product(username VARCHAR2)
        RETURN product%rowtype AS
   product_tbl product%rowtype;
BEGIN
  SELECT *
    INTO product_tbl
    FROM product pr
   WHERE pr.kulusername = username;

  RETURN product_tbl;
END;
/
```